# What is the GPUImage "Hue+Colorize" filter ?

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I am searching for a "colorize" filter in GPUImage but can't find it, even in the FilterShowcase app.

I don't know the exact term, a kind of color mask of one single color is applied.

Here is what it looks like in Photoshop :

[image]